# Serialisation of alternative internal fields

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

If Identical programs are issued out, but only differ with a single change to the data structure of the field `bar`.

1. Will the serialisation be different, when `bar` is represented the same value `HelloWorld`?
2. Will the serialisation/deserialisation process not be exchangeable between the different versions?

Example:

```
//bar only represents "HelloWorld"

//Program 1 field is String
Class foo{
    String bar; //"HelloWorld"
}

//Program 2 field is Character[]
Class foo{
    Character[] bar; //{H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d'}
}

//Program 3 field is ArrayList<Character>
Class foo{
    Arraylist<Character> bar; //{{put('H');put('e');put('l');put('l');put('o');put('W');put('o');put('r');put('l');put('d')}}
}
```

Is there a name or term for what I'm talking about and looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

Java will not allow you to have multiple classes of the same name in the same package.  You should be seeing errors like "foo already defined" when you try to compile your example.

Java Serialization includes the class, so serialization into class "foo" cannot be subsequently deserialized into a different "foo2" class.  This also means that the serialization of "foo" will always be distinct from the serialization of "foo2".

If your goal is to have a "foo" class that exposes its String as either a character array or and ArrayList, you can do that all in a single class like.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class TooManyFoo {
    private final String bar;

    public TooManyFoo( String bar ) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public Character[] getBarAsArray() {
        Character[] barAsArray = new Character[bar.length()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < barAsArray.length; i++ ) {
            barAsArray[i] = Character.valueOf( bar.charAt( i ) );
        }
        return barAsArray;
    }

    public List<Character> getBarAsList() {
        List<Character> barAsList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for ( char c : bar.toCharArray() ) {
            barAsList.add( Character.valueOf( c ) );
        }
        return barAsList;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, most developers would just expect to work the the String bar in foo directly through the getter.

My point is, Java serialization includes class so you must deserialize into the same class.

Comment: I should have explained myself more clearly. I was imaging alternative programs issued to alternative users. Would they be able to exchange byte data of the serialisation of the alternative Foo classes. if the internal representation is subtly different. I should adjust my question.

Comment: I just Re-read this and edited my question. the inclusion of the class is useful info. If the byte-arrays are exchanged between different programs will the bytes streams be exchangeable.